# How to execute javascript methods generated in html onlclick events

Tags: javascript

The updateValue() method isn't firing and I'm not sure how to even debug this using the browser.

```
function generateHtmlTableRow() {
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    $("#results").append(tr);

    var someTextData = "test";
    tr.append("<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"TestButton\" onclick=\"updateValue(someTextData);\" /></td>");
}

function updateValue(newText) {
    alert(newText);
}
```

Comment: Don't use inline JavaScript for your event handler. Use jQuery's `.on()` function with event delegation.

Comment: Also, if you use single quotes to wrap your string, no need to escape the double quotes.

Comment: Try this..  `tr.append("<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"TestButton\" onclick=\"updateValue('"+someTextData+"');\" /></td>");`

Comment: You can debug using the browser console.

Comment: @j08691 could you provide an example of this?

Comment: Sure. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3fpxqw1u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated html is the problem. It cannot reference a variable in the scope of the `generateHtmlTableRow` function. So it will work:

```js
function generateHtmlTableRow() {
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    $("#results").append(tr);

    var someTextData = "test";
    tr.append("<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"TestButton\" onclick=\"updateValue('" + someTextData + "');\" /></td>");
}

function updateValue(newText) {
    alert(newText);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('log');
  generateHtmlTableRow();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: This a bad example of solving such a problem, this is not how it should be done.

Comment: Thanks, I knew my syntax was off somehow!

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to do this is to

- Store the `someData` values in HTML5 `data-` attributes when you create the `<tr>`. jQuery has the [`.data()` function](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for this purpose.
- Use a [delegated event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) that catches all button clicks inside the `<table>`. The event handler can then retrieve the data again easily.

```js
function generateTableRow(someData) {
  $("<tr><td><button class='test'>TestButton</button></td></tr>")
    .data("value", someData)
    .appendTo("#results");
}

$(function(){
  $("#results").on("click", "button.test", function () {
    var value = $(this).closest("tr").data("value");
    alert(value);
  });
  generateTableRow("test 1");
  generateTableRow("test 2");
  generateTableRow("test 3");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="results"></table>
```

Comment: +1 This is a more elegant way to implement but I chose @Meiko's answer as it was answering and explaining what I was doing wrong not a better way to do it. In the future I will refactor to use this instead however.

Comment: No worries, as long as you use it to learn it's all right.  Thanks for the feedback.